# Outline in Beamer with multiple title pages

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I do a thesis in many (independent) articles or essays. I need a good way for the presentation. My goal is to have one Beamer file containing the essays. I code the Beamer as following:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,xcolor=table,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{default}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\title[] %optional
{\sc General Title}
\author[] % (optional)
{My Name}
\frame{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\titlepage
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHAPTER 1
\title %optional
{CHAP 1 title}

\frame{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\titlepage
}

\section{Section 1 in chap 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.1 in chap 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.2 in chap 1}
\section{Section 2 in chap 1}
\subsection{subsection 2.1 in chap 1}
\subsection{subsection 2.2 in chap 1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHAPTER 2
\title %optional
{CHAP 2 title}

\frame{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\titlepage
}

\section{Section 1 in chap 2}
\subsection{subsection 1.1 in chap 2}
\subsection{subsection 1.2 in chap 2}
\section{Section 2 in chap 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.1 in chap 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.2 in chap 2}
```

Everything is Ok, and I have the outline for each new section. But I want to have the outline for each essay. In the essay 1, I need that when recalling the outline, the sections after the second title page do not appear. After the second tile page, I need that when recalling the outline, the section before the second title page do not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could divide your presentation into different `\part`s, this way only the sections of the current part will show up in the toc.

Some other comments:

- to pass multiple options to the `xcolor` package, the correct syntax is `\documentclass[xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames,table},10pt]{beamer}`
- the syntax `\frame{...}` is obsolete, better write `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`
- instead of `\thispagestyle{empty}` you could use the `plain` frame option
- instead of putting formatting instructions inside the `\title` macro, I'd suggest to temporarily modify the title font instead

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames,table},10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{default}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\scshape}
\title[] %optional
{General Title}
\author[] % (optional)
{My Name}
\begin{frame}[plain]
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\part{essay 1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHAPTER 1
\title %optional
{CHAP 1 title}

\begin{frame}[plain]
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Section 1 in chap 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.1 in chap 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.2 in chap 1}
\section{Section 2 in chap 1}
\subsection{subsection 2.1 in chap 1}
\subsection{subsection 2.2 in chap 1}

\part{essay 2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHAPTER 2
\title %optional
{CHAP 2 title}

\begin{frame}[plain]
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1 in chap 2}
\subsection{subsection 1.1 in chap 2}
\subsection{subsection 1.2 in chap 2}
\section{Section 2 in chap 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.1 in chap 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.2 in chap 2}

\end{document}
```